# Is there any way to get values from an unrelated table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, relationship, powerbi-desktop, dashboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSxrB.png)I am new to Power BI. I have a data model which contains two fact tables i.e. SALES and RETURNS. I have some dimension tables like CALENDAR, PRODUCTS, CUSTOMERS etc. My RETURNS and CUSTOMERS do not share any relationship because RETURNS does not hold any CustomerKey column. But I am curious to know the total returned quantity according to CustomerKey or CustomerName. Is there any way to crack it through DAX?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it should depends on your relationship between other tables. For example, do you create relationship between RETURNS and PRODUCTS? PRODUCTS and CUSTOMERS? Then RETURNS and CUSTOMERS will have relationship through PRODUCTS as bridge table. If not then please let me see your database of each tables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is a relationship between RETURNS and PRODUCTS. SALES is connected with CALENDAR, PRODUCTS, CUSTOMERS, TERRITORY and RETURNS is connected with CALENDAR, PRODUCTS, and TERRITORY. There is no relationship between CUSTOMERS and PRODUCT. Is there any solution to make a bridge between CUSTOMERS and RETURNS then?  I have added a picture of my data model to the original query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you create a switching between iad_id and customer_id from the model view section, you will have established a connection between the two tables, and then you can Decipher the total number of refunds by Decrypting the iad_id field

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs to choose either of PRODUCTS, CALENDAR, TERRITORY as bridge table.

Here is the step:

1. change one direction relationship between PRODUCTS and SALES into two direction;

   *double click the relation line and choose 'both' in cross filter direction:*

[image]

2. Then CUSTOMERS table will set relationship with RETURNS via PRODUCTS table productkey column. You can create visuals in dashboard with columns from CUSTOMERS and RETURNS and get total returned quantity under each CustomerKey or CustomerName followed by productkey.

Show me your pbix file so I can make it clear if you catch any problems.